# Манипуляция флеш-страницей

Tags: usercontrol, flash, плагин

Есть страница, полносью сделанная на флеше. Необходимо выполнять некоторые действия автоматически (кликать по кнопкам, скроллить страничку, по возможности отслеживать какие-то события). Знаю, было когда-то дополнение к фаерфокс, позволяющее писать какие-то команды-скрипты, которые выполнялись на странице. Синтаксис написания прост. Указываются координаты на странице и действие (клик и т.д.), но ни название, ни принцип работы не помню. JavaScript'ом, наверное, вмешаться не получится. Какие еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoIt](https://www.google.ru/search?q=autoit&sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> **AutoIt** — свободно распространяемый язык для автоматизации выполнения задач в Microsoft Windows.